# Run .m file in terminal

Tags: scripting

I have the following .m file

```
(* ::Package:: *)
(* ::Input:: *)
(*out=1+1;*)
(*Print["Test"];*)
(*Export["/path/test.txt",out];*)
```

and I am trying to run it in the terminal with
`math -run -nomprompt < name.m`

but it doesn't work. I have changed the permissions of the .m file.

Comment: It works for me when I uncomment the last 3 lines of the code, recognizing that `-nomprompt` contains a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: They have to be initialization cells to be able to run them.

Comment: They have to be initialization cells to not export as comments in the autogenerated .m file